# How to select nodes by matching text

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

If I have a bunch of elements like:

```
<p>A paragraph <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Apple</li><li>Orange</li></ul></p>
```

Is there a built-in method in Nokogiri that would get me all `p` elements that contain the text "Apple"? (The example element above would match, for instance).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Nokogiri can do this (now) using jQuery extensions to CSS:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.at('p:contains("bar")').text.strip
=> "bar"
```

Comment: if you replaced bar with a another text like : "google encrypted \"google drive\" this year" it produces an error, any ideas how to properly escape the " character ?

Comment: Try using `&quot;` instead of the embedded quotes?

Comment: Is there any way to do this without knowing what type of element contains the text? If I do `doc.at(':contains("bar")')` (i.e. without specifying a `p` element) then I get the whole document.

Comment: It's okay, I found the answer `doc.at(':contains("foo"):not(:has(:contains("foo")))')` here https://makandracards.com/makandra/38803-find-the-innermost-dom-element-that-contains-a-given-string

Answer (score 55):

Here is an XPath that works:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(DATA)
p doc.xpath('//li[contains(text(), "Apple")]')

__END__
<p>A paragraph <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Apple</li><li>Orange</li></ul></p>
```

Comment: I prefer this one since it returns all instances of matching nodes compare to the accepted answer which only returns 1 node.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this very easily with [Nikkou](https://github.com/tombenner/nikkou):

```rb
doc.search('p').text_includes('bar')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for suggesting nikkou, i have a feeling this will save me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 6):

Try using this XPath:

```
p = doc.xpath('//p[//*[contains(text(), "Apple")]]')
```