# How do I select an element with its text content via CSS not XPath?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

"[Nokogiri: How to select nodes by matching text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474688/nokogiri-how-to-select-nodes-by-matching-text)" can do this via XPath, however, I am looking for a way to use a CSS select that matches the text of element.

PyQuery and PHPQuery can do this. Isn't there a jQuery API lib for Ruby?

Comment: Is this a Nokogiri(Ruby) or a JQuery(Javascript) question?

Answer (score 15):

Nokogiri (now) implements jQuery selectors, making it possible to search the text of a node:

For instance:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.at('p:contains("bar")').text.strip
=> "bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

Cannot be done with pure CSS, you'll have to mix it with Ruby code

```
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<p>A paragraph <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Apple</li><li>Orange</li></ul></p>")
  p doc.css('li').select{|li|li.text =~ /Apple/}
```