# Using Nokogiri to select a block of HTML based on text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have the following block of HTML:

```
<tr>
   <th>Consignment Service Code</th>
   <td>ND16</td>
</tr>
```

What I'm ultimately trying to pull is that `ND16` string, but to do that, I need to select the `<tr>` based on the text `Consignment Service Code`.

I'm using Nokogiri already to parse the HTML, so it'd be great to just keep using that.

So, how can I select that block of HTML based on the text "`Consignment Service Code`"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nokogiri: How to select nodes by matching text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474688/nokogiri-how-to-select-nodes-by-matching-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc=Nokogiri::HTML::parse <<-eot
<tr>
   <th>Consignment Service Code</th>
   <td>ND16</td>
</tr>
eot

node = doc.at_xpath("//*[text()='Consignment Service Code']/following-sibling::*[1]")
puts node.text
# >> ND16
```

Here's an additional try, which might help you to get going:

```
## parent node
parent_node = doc.at_xpath("//*[text()='Consignment Service Code']/..")
puts parent_node.name # => tr

## to get the child td
puts parent_node.at_xpath("//td").text # => ND16

puts parent_node.to_html

#<tr>
#<th>Consignment Service Code</th>
#   <td>ND16</td>
#</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way.

Use Nokogiri's `css` method to find the appropriate `tr` nodes and then select the ones that have the desired text in the `th` tag. Finally, work with the selected nodes and extract the `td` values:

```
require 'nokogiri'

str = '<tr>
   <th>Consignment</th>
   <td>ND15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Consignment Service Code</th>
   <td>ND16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Consignment Service Code</th>
   <td>ND17</td>
</tr>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(str)
nodes = doc.css('tr')
           .select{|el| 
             el.css('th').text =~ /^Consignment Service Code$/
           }

nodes.each do |el|
  p el.css('td').text
end
```

Output is:

```
"ND16"
"ND17"
```

Comment: You can use this http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/ as you are using `#css` method...

Comment: You might want to explain how that link applies to Nokogiri's `css` and this answer.