# How to check if one of the options in my select menu contains text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with Nokogiri.  Is there a way I can tell, with Nokogiri, that one of the options in my select menu contains the word "Results" in its text field (that would be visible to the end user)?

I have:

```
options = doc.css("#menu_id option")
```

And I can cycle through all of them, checking the text, but I figured there might be a CSS-selector expression or something similar I can do with Nokogiri that would tell me this answer more quickly.

Comment: Why? You should know whether the menu contains that because you programmed the view. Is this for a unit test? Also, you probably want to adjust something on your system because it's inserting curly-quotes in places that would be syntactically incorrect in code; They're extremely difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri supports jQuery's `:contains` selector, which selects nodes with the given content:

```
doc.css(“#menu_id option:contains('Results'")
```

You could also do it with an XPath, which has more power but is more verbose:

```
doc.xpath('//*[@id='menu_id']//option[contains(text(), "Results")]')
```

See "[Nokogiri: How to select nodes by matching text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474688/nokogiri-how-to-select-nodes-by-matching-text)".

Answer (score 1):

This is the generic way to do it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <select id="menu_id">
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('#menu_id option').any?{ |option| option.text == 'foo' } # => true
```

That looks to see if the text, not the value, is `"foo"`.

```
doc.search('#menu_id option').any?{ |option| option.text['foo'] } # => true
```

That looks to see if the text, not the value, contains the sub-string `"foo"`.

```
doc.search('#menu_id option').any?{ |option| option['value'] == 'foo' } # => true
```

That looks to see if the `value` parameter matches the word `"foo"`.

Similarly, they'll tell you whether something *doesn't* match:

```
doc.search('#menu_id option').any?{ |option| option.text == 'bar' } # => false
doc.search('#menu_id option').any?{ |option| option.text['bar'] } # => false
doc.search('#menu_id option').any?{ |option| option['value'] == 'bar' } # => false
```

I would probably rely on Nokogiri's implementation of the jQuery extensions that @gmcnaughton mentioned but that's how I am. YMMV.